# Running PHP code before loading template in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, model-view-controller

Since I've only started using Wordpress recently, I'm still trying to figure how to run PHP code prior to loading the template for a particular post.

I'm talking about code which would be executed in the contoller class in a MVC structure.

Obviously it's tempting to stuff it in the page's template file, but I'm sure this won't be exactly qualified as best practice.
Any suggestions on this matter? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actions(list of executing) on front part WordPress:

```
muplugins_loaded
registered_taxonomy
registered_post_type
plugins_loaded
sanitize_comment_cookies
setup_theme
load_textdomain
after_setup_theme
auth_cookie_malformed
auth_cookie_valid
set_current_user
init
widgets_init
register_sidebar
wp_register_sidebar_widget
wp_default_scripts
wp_default_styles
admin_bar_init
add_admin_bar_menus
wp_loaded
parse_request
send_headers
parse_query
pre_get_posts
posts_clauses
posts_selection
wp
template_redirect
get_header
wp_head
wp_enqueue_scripts
wp_print_styles
wp_print_scripts
get_search_form
loop_start
the_post
get_template_part_content
loop_end
get_sidebar
dynamic_sidebar
get_search_form
pre_get_comments
wp_meta
get_footer
get_sidebar
wp_footer
wp_print_footer_scripts
admin_bar_menu
wp_before_admin_bar_render
wp_after_admin_
bar_render
shutdown
```

So, if You need some magic without all core functions, You can put your code into own mu-plugin for example, and it will execute on start(`muplugins_loaded` action).
For basic functionality and with theme functions - `wp_loaded`, etc. see the list above.

Usual, uses `init` action(cause WordPress is fully loaded, but without header and other stuff), example:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_func' );
function my_func() {
    // Write some code here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nik for providing me with the actions list and an answer to my question. More Practical: I need to run a (PHP) calculation tool which takes data from a submitted form. Where'd I put the calculation tool code? Init hook?

Comment: @DurianNangka
You can put the calculation action on submit or on click button of form. Use for it Ajax tech. to get dynamic calculation and getting results without reload of page. All You need just JS and one function into the functions.php file of theme.